# почему в пхп-файле пишут <?php ?> несколько раз?

Tags: php

часто встречается код, который содержит открытие и закрытие тегов php на каждой строке. Например:

```
    <?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'auth_key')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'password_hash')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'password_reset_token')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'password_reset_code')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
```

1. Зачем в обычном php-файле постоянно открывать и закрывать < ?php        ?> ?
2. Влияет ли такое оформление на скорость исполнения файла?

Comment: Открывают и закрывают для чередоаания кода php и html

Comment: так в том то и дело, что код пхп идёт сплошняком, как в данном примере

Comment: Бывает, что просто копипастят из других файлов. Может, просто удалили хтмл между строками. Короче, не надо заморачиваться на эту тему

Answer (score 0):

`<?= ... ?>` и `<?php ... ?>` не одно и тоже, потому что первое равносильно `<?php echo ... ?>`

На скорость выполнения это не влияет.